# Model NaN in a Double value in graphql-spqr

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

There is no standard to represent [NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) and [INFINITY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) in neither the [Graphql](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Float-Value) and also in [JSON](http://json.org/).

In JavaScript, `JSON.stringify(0/0)` and `JSON.stringify(1/0)` will just return string `null`.

It cause little trouble when I am providing GraphQL endpoint with Java backed. My value could be any valid `Double` in Java.

```
    @GraphQLQuery
    private Double precentage;
```

I have few workarounds and I could patch it in a setter which I am doing.
Just wonder if there is a de-facto standards to handle it in a nicer way.

Comment: I haven't worked with the Java implementation, but I imagine you should be able to create a custom scalar type by creating an instance of the `GraphQLScalarType` class as shown [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/master/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/util/Scalars.java). This way you can create a scalar that can accept, for example, `"NaN"`, "Infinity" and any floating point value as valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about this at some point as well...
The current situation is that `Double` (the Java type) gets mapped to GraphQL `Float` scalar, which can not represent `NaN` or infinity.
What you could do is implement your own scalar (called e.g. `Double`) and decide on how you will deal with the these special cases (use the existing scalar implementations as a guideline). Perhaps use strings like `NaN`, `+Infinity`, `-Infinity`? The worst part is whatever convention you settle on, the client needs to be aware of it too, as JSON has no representation for these values either.

Once you have a custom scalar you're happy with, you can implement a super simple `TypeMapper` that supports `Double` (the Java type) and returns this new scalar.

Or to answer your original question - no, unfortunately there's nothing out of the box yet in either graphql-java or SPQR. But I'm happy to extend SPQR's custom scalars to deal wiht this... If you come up with a good strategy, do ping me.